# Slide to anchor in plain html

Tags: html, css

I want to create a sliding effect as seen in http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ but with plain html and css. is that possible? if so, how?

If it is html5 and css3, no problem (I won't use IE (-: )

thanks in advance!

Comment: Err… there are lots of different sliding effects show there. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: just a smooth scrolling effect on the anchors made with <a name> and <a href> in html and css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this demo:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SmoothTransitionsResponsiveLayout/

And the explanation here:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/12/css-only-responsive-layout-with-smooth-transitions/

It shows how to set up a CSS3 scrollTo transition, however, only works with the link anchors - not the scrollbar - which is a deal-breaker for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the psuedo `:target` to achieve this, quick Google search fetched [this example](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/3392/example4.html) - it gives a detailed write up on how it works [on this page](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-target-based-interfaces/). I'm sure Google will bring up other results and more examples to get it working how you want it :)

Of course only certain new browsers will understand `:target` but if this doesn't bother you then you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: when I apply a regular <a name> and <a href>, I get a jump to the section below(or above), I just want to add smooth scrolling to that (as seen on http://www.w3.org/html/logo/ )

Comment: sorry, only looked at the example, started reading now, might be my answer... trying...